# JavaScript Bitwise operations

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I would like to store all currently-pressed keycodes in a single variable by using bitwise operations when the key is pressed and when the key is released.

I'm not sure how to properly use bitwise operations, but I know this will be very simple to someone who does.

Once complete, it should be simple to see which key is currently depressed by asking "is this key's code in the variable?"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Greg: You didn't have the time to read my answer for your previous question, which answered this question as well, before deleting your previous question?

Comment: The previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782673/javascript-bitwise-operation

Comment: @KennyTM: How did you find that?

Comment: @Matti: Browser history.

Comment: @KennyTM: Ah. Here I was thinking you could find closed questions from somewhere...

Comment: There are valid answers to this but there's no reason to do such a thing in JS. Memory is not limited and the performance of bitwise operators in JS is about the same as normal mathematical operators. Just use an object whose keys correspond to each keycode and related values `true/false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible the way you want to do it. [Have a look at the available keycodes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx). There you see, that e.g. `backspace` is `8` and `tab` is `9`.

In binary, that would be `1000` and `1001`. Using binary operators, you would use OR `|` to "combine" the values, which would result in `1001`.

You would check if a value is set via AND `&`, e.g. `1001` & `1000` to see, if the backspace key was pressed. Unfortunately, this would also evaluate to `true` if only the tab key was pressed (as its value is `1001`).

That said, you can only use such bitwise comparison techniques, if the different values you want to test are powers of 2 **only**, i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 and so on, as this represents in binary `1`, `10`, `100`, `1000`,...

For example if we can have a `status` variable and possible statuses would be `OPEN = 2`, `LIGHT ON = 4` and `ALARM ON = 8`.
Assume that it is `OPEN` and `LIGHT ON`, i.e.

```
  0010
| 0100
------- 
  0110
```

Here we can easily check whether the `ALARM` is on, be using AND: `0110 & 1000 = 0`. But if we would encode `ALARM ON` with `6 = 0110`, we could not check this.

---

What you could do is, to map the key codes to a some power of 2 value and apply binary operations there. [The Wikipedia article about **bitmasks** might be worth reading.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmask)

I hope my explanation was somehow clear.

Answer (score 5):

This is technically impossible to do in a single variable, no datatype in javascript can store the 256 bits required to hold the bitmask (which supports bitwise operations), you will need to use an array instead.

Also, unless you have text to speech software which you've macroed to magically execute js functions for you, asking your computer: "is this key's code in the variable?" won't do squat.

The way you would do it would be to initialize an array with 256 indexes, and then when a key is pressed, you find the relevant index and set it to `true` and when a key is released, you set it to `false`

It's the only way to do it. There actually isn't any other.

Comment: Well, you could technically have an array of 9 numbers and still use bitwise operations... it'd be silly though.

Comment: You could, but RAM isn't exactly a precious resource nowadays :S

Answer (score 0):

javascript bit operations are generally reliable for the first 31 bits, and things go downhill from there. So, you can 31 different keys which you have given a value to act as a flag. for instance, if you wanted to track the four arrows and A and B, you would do something like this.

```
var KEYS = { 
    LEFT:  1 << 0,
    UP:    1 << 1,
    RIGHT: 1 << 2,
    DOWN:  1 << 3,
    A:     1 << 4,
    B:     1 << 5
}

var flags = 0;

myElement.addEventListener ('keydown', function (e) { 

    switch (e.keyCode) {

        case 37: // left
        flags = flags | KEYS.LEFT;
        break;
        case 38: // up
        flags = flags | KEYS.UP;
        break;

        ... etc ...

    }

}

} , false);

function checkKeys () {

    if ( (flags & KEYS.LEFT) === KEYS.LEFT)
        alert('LEFT key pressed');
    }

    if ( (flags & KEYS.UP) === KEYS.UP )
        alert('UP key pressed');
    }

    ... etc ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is such a thing as a ByteArray in JavaScript but if so, you could do it much like how this fellow did his logic in ActionScript3. While I am a big fan of bitflags & bitwise operations, I don't get the bitshifting he's doing and much of his code is way over my head.  I just know it works on as3 projects I've worked on.

Also if you'd like to learn more about bitflags & bitwise operations (aside from the bitshifting) check out this article - http://jwopitz.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/using-bitflags-and-bitwise-math/

Source - https://github.com/richardlord/Asteroids/blob/master/src/no-dependencies/net/richardlord/input/KeyPoll.as

```
     //init the bytearray
     _states = new ByteArray();
     _states.writeUnsignedInt( 0 );
     _states.writeUnsignedInt( 0 );
     _states.writeUnsignedInt( 0 );
     _states.writeUnsignedInt( 0 );
     _states.writeUnsignedInt( 0 );
     _states.writeUnsignedInt( 0 );
     _states.writeUnsignedInt( 0 );
     _states.writeUnsignedInt( 0 );

    //on a keydown listener (note the bitwise OR for adding
    _states[ event.keyCode >>> 3 ] |= 1 << ( event.keyCode & 7 );

    //on a keyup listener (note the bitwise AND plus bitwise NOT
    states[ ev.keyCode >>> 3 ] &= ~(1 << (ev.keyCode & 7));

    //check for keydown
    return ( states[ keyCode >>> 3 ] & (1 << (keyCode & 7)) ) != 0;

    //check for keyup
    return ( states[ keyCode >>> 3 ] & (1 << (keyCode & 7)) ) == 0;
```